# Vagrant private network fixed ip

Tags: networking, vagrant, libvirt

I attempted to setup some VM with a fixed IP private network. I am using the `vagrant-libvirt` provider. The below is my `Vagrantfile`.

```rb
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.ssh.insert_key = false
  config.vm.synced_folder '.', '/vagrant', disabled: true
  config.vm.define "vagrant1" do |vagrant1|
    vagrant1.vm.box = "debian/jessie64"
    vagrant1.vm.network "private_network", ip:"10.1.1.11", auto_config: false
  end
  config.vm.define "vagrant2" do |vagrant2|
    vagrant2.vm.box = "debian/jessie64"
    vagrant2.vm.network "private_network", ip:"10.1.1.12", auto_config: false
  end
  config.vm.define "vagrant3" do |vagrant3|
    vagrant3.vm.box = "debian/jessie64"
    vagrant3.vm.network "private_network", ip:"10.1.1.13", auto_config: false
  end
end
```

I was expecting to see the 3 VMs to have fixed IPs specified by my `ip` settings. But when I got my machines up (`vagrant up --provider=libvirt`), the private network interface is never exactly the one I set.

For example, I'd expect `vagrant1` to have `10.1.1.11` as IP. Instead, it sometimes become `10.1.1.15`. Sometimes `10.1.1.56` or else.

What is wrong with my setup?

Versions

- Vagrant: 2.0.2
- OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is a [vagrant issue with newer Debian](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/8686), which has changed to systemd for network configurations. It is not related to [vagrant-libvirt](https://github.com/vagrant-libvirt/vagrant-libvirt/issues/867).

Older versions of vagrant's host script still presume the network config is done in the old way. So even your vagrant configuration is done right, the guest OS script fails to do the desired networking configurations.

Newer version of vagrant should have fixed this, but it is not on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

So the solution would be either to:

- upgrade your vagrant; or
- use non-debian host OS box.